# What does bindtextdomain in PHP do

Tags: php

I might be blind, but I don't see any good explanation [here](https://www.php.net/bindtextdomain).
So, what does bindtextdomain do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"The `bindtextdomain()` function sets the path for a domain. It returns the full pathname for the domain currently being set."**

Taken from [here](http://www.php-editors.com/php_manual/function.bindtextdomain.html).

It looks like `bindtextdomain()` was taken from C code - there's a bit more of an overview [here](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=bindtextdomain), but I'm not sure how much of that applies to the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gettext.php :

The gettext functions implement an NLS (Native Language Support) API which can be used to internationalize your PHP applications. Please see the gettext documentation for your system for a thorough explanation of these functions or view the docs at » http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html

Also, see the user notes on this page:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php